# Clicking Taskbar Window Opens in Background instead of Foreground

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

After the Cumulative 2023-12 Windows 10 update, clicking on the windows in the tray loads the window... in the background.

I have to alt + tab twice and then am able to get the window to the foreground.
This only occurs when I click the window from the tray button. If I use AHK to open the specific window, without 1st clicking the tray, it opens fine.

Something is definitely weird with the tray.
I've reproduced this after closing all my apps including Powertoys... reported this to Microsoft on Feedback hub.
Not sure what else it could be other than the update. Seems too huge an issue for others not to have made a fuss.

Things I've tried:

- full reboot

Haven't tried safe mode but I'm sure it won't replicate there.

Build info:
Edition Windows 10 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎19/‎2022
OS build    19045.3803
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19053.1000.0

Comment: Does you mean that you click an icon that is pinned to the tray, or that you click an already-open window? Try as first step to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Have you rebooted since? Not turn off and on, actually rebooted? These weird issues sometimes go away and don't come back after a reboot. You did not mention a reboot in your post.

Comment: I tried rebooting and the DISM commands and it didn't fix it. I am now believing that I was wrong and it is related to one of my Autohotkey scripts which trigger the tray because it is no longer happening! (without a restart) Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange but this was actually a bug with FSCapture running in administrator mode. I've always had FSCapture running in admin mode before but after this most recent Windows update it caused a conflict (some sort of overlay on the tray maybe) that caused this issue.

Resolved by running FSCapture as non-admin user.